# Flutter ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: ios, flutter

I have tried to upload the my flutter app to the appstore but each time I get an error saying:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

I can't see the dependency that are using the UIWebView in py pubspec.yaml.

My dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  native_device_orientation: ^0.3.0
  pin_code_text_field: ^1.5.1
  # sms:
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  path: ^1.6.4
  sqflite_common: ^1.0.1
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:
  image_picker: ^0.6.6+1
  badges: ^1.1.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^1.0.4
  photo_view: ^0.9.2
  carousel_slider: ^2.1.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.10
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.5.8
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  http:
  meta:
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.2
  shared_preferences:
  path_provider:
  protobuf: ^1.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5345
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.4.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  string_validator: ^0.1.4
  flutter_inappwebview: 3.4.0+2
  youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+6
  country_pickers: ^1.3.0
  auto_direction: ^0.0.4+1
  bubble_bottom_bar: ^1.2.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  overlay_support: ^1.0.4
  video_player: 0.10.11+2
  pdf: ^1.9.0
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
  share_extend: "^1.1.9"
  dio: ^3.0.9
  flutter_qr_bar_scanner: ^1.0.1
  flutter_luban: ^0.1.11
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  flutter_ringtone_player: ^2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the module that is causing the trouble by running `grep -r "UIWebView" .`

The most likely culprit is `flutter_qr_bar_scanner` as described in [this issue](https://github.com/contactlutforrahman/flutter_qr_bar_scanner/issues/11) in their repository.